# C# How to use how to MathType 7 SDK to read word and convert function variables EQ in word to MathType

Tags: c#

C# How to use how to MathType 7 SDK to read word and convert function variables EQ in word to MathType

I have looked at the following url
https://docs.wiris.com/en/mathtype/office_tools/mathtype-sdk/apidocumentation#mathpage_api
but did not find the relevant api

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked refers to unmanaged (DLL) libraries. If MathType doesn't have a managed (.NET, like C# code) library you would need to use [the PInvoke system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/consuming-unmanaged-dll-functions)